# Rewriting ODE in terms of a different variable ($z=e^x$)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem, sturm-liouville

Given the ODE
$$x^2M''+xM'+\lambda M = 0$$
where $1<x<L$, with boundary conditions $M(1) = 0$, $M(L)=0$, we can rewrite it in the Sturm-Liouville form and get
$$\left[M'\exp\left(\int\limits_0^L{\frac{1}{x}}dx\right)\right]'+\lambda x^{-2}\exp\left(\int\limits_0^L{\frac{1}{x}}dx\right) M=0$$
This equation becomes
$$LM''+\lambda Lx^{-2}M = 0$$
for some constant $L>0$, because $\exp\left(\int\limits_0^L{\frac{1}{x}}dx\right)=L$.

Now, to rewrite this equation in terms of $z=e^x$, is it sufficient to do the following?

$\frac{dM}{dx}=\frac{dM}{dz}\frac{dz}{dx}=zM'(z)$, thus we get the equation
$$L\left[zM'(z)\right]'+\lambda Lz^{-2}M(z)=0$$
or simply
$$\left[zM'(z)\right]'+\lambda z^{-2}M(z)=0$$

I'm not sure if everything I did above is correct, so I would appreciate your feedback.

Comment: You seem to introduce an integrating factor $e^{\int_0^L \frac{dx}{x}}$ that is not a function of $x$ but a constant. This is strange and should do nothing to your equation. I also don't see how $x^2 M'' + xM' + \lambda M = 0$ is equivalent to $M'' + \lambda x^{-2} M = 0$ ?! You seem to just have deleted the $M'$ term. If you want to write it on SL form then this is $\frac{d}{dx}\left[x\frac{dM}{dx}\right] = - \lambda \frac{1}{x}M$ and taking $z = \log(x)$ then it becomes $\frac{d^2M}{dz^2} = - \lambda M$.

Comment: @Winther So, I guess the integrating factor should be an indefinite integral then. Then we would have $\exp\left(\int{\frac{1}{x}}dx\right)=Ax$ for some constant $A>0$. Is this correct?

Comment: Then the equation transformed into the Sturm-Liouville form should be $(AxM')' + \lambda A x^{-1} M = 0 \iff (xM')' + \lambda x^{-1} M = 0$, which is the one you wrote above.

Comment: Yes. You can take $A=1$ (or cancel it from the equaton), but that is correct. Notice that you can write the equation as $x\frac{d}{dx}\left[x \frac{dM}{dx}\right] + \lambda M = 0$. The presence of the operator $x\frac{d}{dx} = \frac{d}{d\log(x)}$ motivates a change of variables $z = \log(x)$.

Comment: And then after the change of variables the equation becomes $(z\log(z)M')' + \lambda \frac{1}{log(z)}M = 0$?

Comment: You seem to have taken $x = \log(z)$. Try the opposite: $z = \log(x)$ or equivalently $x = e^{z}$. This will lead to a much simpler equation.

Comment: But shouldn't it be $x = \log(z)$ instead of $z=\log(x)$?

Comment: The thing is that the problem gives $z=e^x$, so I thought that $x=\log(z)$ then.

Comment: Try both and figure out for yourself what works best. One of the two leads to a a  much simpler ODE than the other.

Comment: Unfortunately, I didn't get your substitution method. First of all, we are given $z=e^x$, not $z=\ln(x)$. Then, I didn't understand how your $M'$ term got cancelled.

Comment: Forget what you are given and try to think for yourself. You have tried $z = e^x$ above and it did not work very well. You found a mess of an equation that you cannot easily solve. If you try $z = \log(x)$ it will work much better for you. The $M'$ term does not get cancelled - it gets transformed: in the original equation $M' = \frac{dM}{dx}$ while in the equation I got above the derivative is in terms of $z$. Note that $\frac{d^2M}{dz^2} = x~\frac{d}{dx}\left[x \frac{dM}{dx}\right] = x^2\frac{d^2M}{dx^2} + x\frac{dM}{dx}$ so the second derivative wrt $z$ "contains" $\frac{dM}{dx}$.

Comment: I see that your assumption for $z$ makes things much easier. It's just that I don't understand how we can kind of reverse the meaning of $z$ with respect to $x$. What I mean is that my prof will probably not like it.

Comment: There is no "reverse the meaning" here. $z$ is just the variable name I used. If you like it better call the new variable $y = \log(x)$ instead, it does not matter what you call it. The hint given is obviously a typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$x^2\frac{d^2M}{dx^2}+x\frac{dM}{dx}+\lambda M(x)=0$$
The change of variable $\quad z=e^x\quad\to\quad x=\ln|z[\quad\to\quad \frac{dz}{dx}=z \quad$ isn't a good idea because it leads to a more complicated form of ODE :

$\frac{dM}{dx}=\frac{dM}{dz}\frac{dz}{dx}=z\frac{dM}{dz}$

$\frac{d^2M}{dx^2}=\left(\frac{d}{dz}\frac{dM}{dx}\right)\frac{dz}{dx}=\frac{d}{dz}\left(z\frac{dM}{dz} \right)z = z^2\frac{d^2M}{dz^2}+z\frac{dM}{dz}$

So, the ODE becomes :

$$\ln^2|z| \left(z^2\frac{d^2M}{dz^2}+z\frac{dM}{dz} \right) +\ln|z|z\frac{dM}{dz}+\lambda M(z)=0$$

A better change of variable would be : 
$$\quad x=e^t \quad\to\quad t=\ln|x|$$
With the same method as above (the chain rule), I let you find the derivatives :

$\frac{dM}{dx}=e^{-t}\frac{dM}{dt}$

$\frac{d^2M}{dx^2}=e^{-2t}\left(\frac{d^2M}{dt^2}-\frac{dM}{dt} \right)$

which leads to :
$$\frac{d^2M}{dt^2}+\lambda M(t)=0$$

COMMENT :

The above method of solving isn't the simplest for this ODE : $x^2\frac{d^2M}{dx^2}+x\frac{dM}{dx}+\lambda M(x)=0 $

A direct method consists in the search of particular solutions on the form $M=x^r$ which leads to the equation :
$$r(r-1)+r+\lambda=0 \quad\to\quad r=\pm\sqrt{-\lambda}$$
$$M(x)=c_1x^{\sqrt{-\lambda}}+c_2x^{-\sqrt{-\lambda}}$$
which can be easily transformed with sinusoidal terms in case of $\lambda>0$.

Answer (score 1):

You can transform to Sturm-Liouville form by dividing by $x$:
$$
                    (xM')'+\frac{\lambda}{x}M = 0.
$$
Whenever you have such a form, you can get rid of the multiplier in the derivative. There is a standard trick when you change the independent variable. In this case, let $M(x) = P(\int\frac{1}{x}dx)$. Then
$$
                      xM'(x) = xP'(\ln(x))\frac{1}{x}=P'(\ln(x)).
$$
Coincidentally (i.e., not generally the way this works out,) you have another $x$ term. So you get
$$
                  x(xM')' + \lambda M = 0 \\
                  P''(\ln(x))+\lambda P(\ln(x)=0 \\
                  P''(y)+\lambda P(y) = 0.
$$
Once you solve for $P$, you get solutions for the original equation of the form $M(x)=P(\ln(x))$. The endpoint conditions for $M$ at $1$ and $L$ become endpoint conditions for $P$ at $0$ and $\ln(L)$.